# Having defines in linker script for memory origin and length

Tags: gcc, linker, linker-scripts, linker-flags

```
MEMORY
{
    RAM (rxai!w) :                  ORIGIN = 0x80000000 LENGTH = 34K
}
```

Lets say I have a section in linker script like above. can i have a define for 0x80000000 and 34K. I want it to look like,

```
MEMORY
{
    RAM (rxai!w) :                  ORIGIN = RAM_ORIGIN LENGTH = RAM_LENGTH
}
```

So my question how to put this define in linker script? I have a script that auto generates the linker script and the defines will be different every time.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that having the defines a different file like common.ld in the following format,

```
RAM_ORIGIN = 0x80000000;
RAM_LENGTH = 34K;
```

works. But this common.ld could not be included directly in the linker script using 'INCLUDE'. If i pass it in the command line as -Wl,common.ld then it works.

Comment: FYI, instead of passing -Wl,common.ld, you can pass -Wl,--defsym=RAM_ORIGIN=0x80000000 and -Wl,--defsym=RAM_LENGTH=34K. Then you can have it specified in your Makefile and not in separate files.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this using the C preprocessor `cpp`.

My linker scripts contain 'variables' that can be 'filled' from the Makefile invoking `cpp` for the actuals:

```
LDCSRC=script.lk.in
LDCDILE=script.lk

$(LDCFILE): $(LDCSRC)
        $(Q)echo CPP $<
        $(Q)$(CPP) $(INCLUDE) -DOBJDIR=$(1)/objs -P -DFORMAT_ELF=$(FORMAT_ELF) -D$$(MACHINE) $$< -o $$@
```

the linker script itself can then be 'beefed up' with `cpp` macros as well:

```
#ifdef COMPILE_RAM
#define ROMFLAGS    WX
#else
#define ROMFLAGS    RX
#endif /* COMPILE_RAM */

MEMORY
{
    _rom (ROMFLAGS) : ORIGIN = TARGET_ADDRESS, LENGTH = 0x00100000
```

In this example, the linker script even `#include`s a C header file (not shown) to define `TARGET_ADDRESS` to ensure we have the same definition in the code and in the linker script. You just need to make sure this *.h file does not contain statements that disturb the linker (should only contain preprocessor definitions).